# OleDb Adapter.Fill() "No value given for one or more parameters"

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I am attempting to pull data from an Access database and display it in a DataViewGrid using the `adapter.fill()` method but keep receiving an error saying "No value given for one or more parameters." This only happens when I attempt to include the variables userID, userPIN, accountNo through concatenation. Those three variables are taken from a previous form's textBox data. When I simplify the query string to `"SELECT * FROM STATEMENT"`, I simply receive a blank dataViewGrid which is also quite odd. I've searched for a solution for days but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

```
string query = "select * from statement where userID = '" + userID + "' and userPIN ='" + userPIN + "' and account_no = " + account_no; //cmd in string form for use with OleDbAdapter
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\ATM Project Folder\\Bank1.accdb";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

// dataset object
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);

// Bind dataset  
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
```

Comment: tip: use queryparamaters to avoid sql injection attack

Comment: select * from statement might return 1Million rows for all we know - suggest limiting by a 'page size' and allow users to page thru data - plenty of samples out there...

Comment: you could try debugging or adding logging statements to help resolve the issue

Comment: I wonder if you're using an email address as a user Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this properly:

```
string query = "select * from statement where userID = @u and userPIN = @p and account_no = @a"

string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\ATM Project Folder\\Bank1.accdb";

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);

//call these in the same order that the placeholders appear in the sql. Ole does not use the names
//when you upgrade to sql server, cease using AddWithValue: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", userID);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", userPIN);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", account_no);


var dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);


dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Never, ever write an SQL like you did in your question; at best, it'll fall over if someone types something that generates a syntax error (such as an apostrophe). At worst it'll cause something like [the vetch hack](https://time.com/4130704/vtech-hack-childrens-toys/?amp=true) where data of over 6 million children was exposed just because a hacker could type a fragment of sql into a website and break into the database

This is really important; concatenating user-supplied data into your SQL is one of the number one ways of providing hackers easy access into a system today. Don't do it; it is always possible to operate more securely

---

The simplest way to use a data adapter to get data is to use the constructor that takes the command string and the connection string, add any parameters that are contained in the command, and call fill. DataAdapter will manage the connection for you. Some people dispose of the adapter; the MSDN official example doesn't so I've omitted that

Access OLE understands @namedParameters but it still treats them positionally; you must add parameters to your command object in the same order that they appear in the statement. The other option you have is to use ? as placeholders. Even though the names aren't used it makes it easier to debug problems. More sophisticated databases do use the names, which means the parameters can be supplied in any order and they can be repeated in the SQL but supplied once in the Parameters. If you do upgrade to SQLServer, cease using AddWithValue as it can cause performance problems, but other databases may not care; check on a case by case basis

Comment: -Thanks I really appreciate the insight. Even when using AddWithValue, it is still throwing the same exception. I will do some more digging and update this post if I find a solution.

Comment: If you pause in the debugger and inspect the values of the UserID, userPIN and account_no variables, what are the values? What are the column types of the  related columns? Post the definition of the table (a screenshot showing all the columns and their data type)